# Wordpress assets - change base url to use S3

Tags: angular, wordpress

I am currently working on a WordPress project where I have successfully fetched and integrated the entire page into an Angular application. However, I am looking to optimize the performance by relocating the assets to an Amazon S3 bucket. Is there a recommended method to modify the base URL for the assets in this scenario?

I initially attempted to manually update the asset URLs in the WordPress project to point to the Amazon S3 bucket. However, this approach didn't yield the desired results as it led to issues with resource loading in the Angular app. Subsequently, I explored configuring a CDN and adjusting the base URL in the Angular application settings, but encountered challenges with proper synchronization.

My expectation was that by transitioning the assets to S3 and updating the base URL, the overall page loading performance in the Angular app would improve. I aimed for a seamless integration where the assets are efficiently retrieved from the S3 bucket, optimizing the user experience. Unfortunately, my current attempts have not yielded the expected outcome, and I'm seeking guidance on the most effective approach to achieve this asset relocation successfully.

Comment: This project might be what you are looking for: https://github.com/humanmade/S3-Uploads/